# In oracle PLSQL i want to compare string which should start with alphabet [A-Z] can contain 0-9, _ and spaces allowed

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to check a variable value which should start with alphabet and should contain only A-Z 0-9 and _ underscore without any space(Oracle PLSQL).

```
BEGIN
IF regexp_like('Name#123','^([0-9]|_)') THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
END IF;
END; 

BEGIN
IF regexp_like('Name#123','^([0-9]|_)') THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You should put everything to match inside brackets, `[A-Z0-9_]`, and you need 2 brackets if I understand you correctly `'^[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*'`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you need to add a $ at the end of your regular expression...

Answer (score 1):

```
IF REGEXP_LIKE(v_str, '[^A-Za-z0-9_]') THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('has special characters'); 
        ELSIF REGEXP_INSTR(v_str, '[A-Za-z]') <> 1 THEN 
            dbms_output.put_line('does not start with character - A-Z or a-z'); 
        ELSE
            dbms_output.put_line('valid columnn name'); 
        END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_LIKE (..., '^[[:alpha:]]\w*$')` or `REGEXP_LIKE (..., '^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$')` which is more or less the same should work. (It just depends if you want to allow for letters aside from A-Z or not.)

Answer (score 0):

```
[[:alpha:]]
```

or

```
\w
```

will accept lowercase letters and any accented letters above the ASCII range. If you really want only the 26 uppercase letters in the ASCII range, then use:

```
where regexp_like(str, '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*$')
```